# Fill Array using while loop PHP

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

I want to fill an array using a while loop. With the following code I only get 1 row of data. But if I print $count it's final value is 432. Any ideas? I've bee trying for days but couldn't figure it out.

```
// Populate objects array

$count = 1;
while($o_result->nextHit()) {

    $t_object = new ca_objects($o_result->get('ca_objects.object_id'));
    $o_c_date = $t_object->getCreationTimestamp();
    $o_lm_date = $t_object->getLastChangeTimestamp();

    $a_objects = array ( array ( 
        'title' => $o_result->get('ca_objects.preferred_labels.name'),
        'type' => $o_result->get('ca_objects.type_id',array(
            'convertCodesToDisplayText' => true))
        )
    );

    $count++;
}

//print results    
foreach ($a_objects as $row) {
    echo $row['title']."<br/>";
    echo $row['type']."<br/>";
}
echo $count."<br/>\n"  ; //This prints 432
```

Comment: You are re-declaring your array on every loop.

Comment: how are you able to code a while loop like this if you don't even know what arrays are ?

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I'm learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are resetting the array `$a_objects` each iteration instead of appending to it.

Do this instead:

```
// outside the loop:
$a_objects = array();

// inside the loop:
$a_objects[] = array (
    'title' => $o_result->get('ca_objects.preferred_labels.name'),
    'type'  => $o_result->get(
                   'ca_objects.type_id',
                   array('convertCodesToDisplayText' => true)
               )
    )
);
```

I also put quotes around the `title` and `type` keys, which you should do as well -- PHP does attempt to guess what you mean if you don't use quotes, but that's a bad practice and you should stop using it.

Comment: Thank you very much, being new to php I tend to make rookie mistakes. I'll accept yout answer as soon as I can.

Comment: @sscarano: Glad to help. Also make sure you read the [tutorial](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) -- reading it now will save you much trouble in the future. Same goes for the features of PHP as well.

Comment: Thanks again. I'll read the tutorial, I'm following a book on php but sometimes I can't see simple mistakes.